# Can't echo items from array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array like so...

```
$myarray = Array (
    [docs] => Array(
        [0] => Array ([property_imgurl] => http://www.example.com/image1.jpg) 
        [1] => Array ([property_imgurl] => http://www.example.com/image2.jpg) 
        [2] => Array ( [property_imgurl] => http://www.example.com/image3.jpg) 
        [3] => Array ( [property_imgurl] => http://www.example.com/image4.jpg)
     )
);
```

I am trying to echo out

```
foreach ($myarray as $myarrays) {
    echo $myarray[property_imgurl];
}
```

But this isn't returning any results, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Would this work? ````echo $myarrays[property_imgurl];````

Comment: Pleaase check this DONTs doc first: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.donts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your key is invalid..

```
foreach ($myarray["docs"] as $myarrays) {
 echo $myarrays["property_imgurl"];
}
```

#### [Live preview](https://eval.in/194135)

Comment: Then there would be no input. OP gave an array with index of `docs`.

Comment: It does. I never meant to imply it didn't. I was just saying that OP gave an array with a defined index (and never mentioned it would change), so having a loop within a loop seems wasteful.

Answer (score 2):

you need to add one more loop try

```
foreach ($myarray as $v) {
   foreach ($v as $v1) {
     echo $v1['property_imgurl'];
   }
}
```

Comment: Why would you need a loop within a loop? Seems wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

Your Array seems to be wrong here..

Try this:

```
$myarray = 
    Array (
       "docs"=> 
           Array(
              "0" => Array ( "property_imgurl" => "http://www.example.com/image1.jpg" ),
              "1" => Array ( "property_imgurl" => "http://www.example.com/image2.jpg" ) ,
              "2" => Array ( "property_imgurl" => "http://www.example.com/image3.jpg" ) ,                 
              "3" => Array ( "property_imgurl" => "http://www.example.com/image4.jpg"                )              )
   );
```

And then iterate your loop like this:

```
        foreach($myarray['docs'] as $key=>$value)
        {
            echo $value['property_imgurl'];
        }
```

Comment: Perhaps your wording is incorrect, but the array (`$myarray`) is correct. (Correct in the sense that is was OP supplied). The only thing that was wrong was the loop.